# image.onload not firing twice in IE7

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-7

It works in IE6, and FireFox; but for some reason not in IE7.

Using ASP.NET on the Page_Init I populate a list of chapters that are links to the image in the book as well as a Javascript array which holds the pageIDs.

ex.

Chapter 1 --> href="javascript:seePage(4);"

Here is the actual code I am using:

```
var availablePages = ['1002_001','1002_002','1002_003','1002_004','1002_005'];

function seePage(index) {
    $get('imgSingle').src = 'graphics/loading.gif';
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'get.jpg.aspx?size=single&id=' + availablePages[index];
    img.onload = function() {
         var single = $get('imgSingle');
         single.src = img.src;
    }
}
```

When I click on Chapter 1, the image loads fine across the board (IE6,7,FF) and clicking on a second chapter link also works; however, in (and only in) IE7 does clicking on the same chapter twice (chap1, chap2, then chap1 again) does the image get stuck on the 'loading' image...

Comment: i love jquery plugin of swap image

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-swapimage/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's caused because IE will cache the image, and the onload event will never fire after it's already been loaded.

You need to position the onload event before the src.

```
var availablePages = ['1002_001','1002_002','1002_003','1002_004','1002_005'];

function seePage(index) {
    $get('imgSingle').src = 'graphics/loading.gif';
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
         var single = $get('imgSingle');
         single.src = img.src;
    }
    img.src = 'get.jpg.aspx?size=single&id=' + availablePages[index];
}
```

Comment: May God bless you with infinite beer sir.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is to check if the image is already loaded with `image.complete`. For instance:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'foo.jpg';
if(img.complete){
    img.onload = function(){ /* ... */ };
} else {
    /* execute something else, or the same. */
}
```

I've experienced this behavior in IE6 and 7.