# Trouble using onLoad with .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems like the click function isn't being binded at all, anyone know why?

```
 <img src='img.jpg'/>

 $("img").each(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = src;
   img.onLoad = function(){
     $(this).click(function(){ alert( 'loaded' }); // < not binding
   } 
 });
```

Don't know what else to try.

Comment: you need to set the onload event before setting the src, and its `onload` not `onLoad`

Comment: so where does the .src go ? inside or after the onLoad?

Comment: @ZeeTee should be after but why would you need to bind click event once image loaded?

Comment: i put it after still not binding

Comment: @PatrickEvans No, you can set `onload` after. JavaScript is single-threaded. The image won't be loaded until the thread of execution returns to the browser. The actual error is `onLoad` instead of `onload`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, I'm telling you you're wrong. It's fine the way it is.

Comment: @meagar, ah i see what you meant, but won't the onload event not get called if the image is cached?

Comment: No, caching isn't going to affect `onload` callbacks. `onload` has nothing to do with the network or where the image is coming from.

Comment: @meagar - actually, in older IE the onload callback is not called on cached images.

Comment: @adeneo Eh, I'll take your word for it. I haven't had to professionally support IE earlier than 10 for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

It's `onload`, not `onLoad`.

The second problem is that you're binding the `click` handler to the newly created `var img`, which is never added to the DOM. You're binding it to the `img = new Image()`, **not** the `<img>` tag you have at the top.

Ignore `this` and try the following:

```
 $("img").each(function(i, el){
   var $el = $(el);
   var src = $el.attr('src');
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = src;

   img.onload = function(){
     $el.click(function(){ alert( 'loaded' }); // < not binding
   } 
 });
```

Comment: @ZeeTee explain then what do you mean by 'not completly'?

Comment: The click event still not binding, the onload() event not firing within the each statement

Comment: So you're saying the $(this) is binded to the onload statement instead of the <img> object in the each statement?

Comment: `this`, inside the `onload`, is `img`, as in the variable `var img =new Image()`. It's no longer the element on the page.

Comment: yup worked, thanks. didnt think it would do that in an onload event

Answer (score 2):

1. events are lowercase
2. `this` inside the onload function is not the image in the DOM
3. you should always set the source after the onload handler is bound
4. you seem to be missing a closing parenthesis in the `alert()`

.

```
$("img").each(function(index, element){
   var img = new Image();

   img.onload = function(){
     $(element).on('click', function(){ 
           alert( 'loaded');
     });
   } 

   img.src = this.src;

   if (img.complete) img.onload();

});
```

Comment: #3 is wrong; you do not need to set the `onload` before the `src`.

Comment: It's a bit old, but here's a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038327/image-onload-not-firing-twice-in-ie7) about this. There have been issues with setting the source before the onload handler, so it's common to make sure you set the source after the onload handler,  as that at least makes sure there are no issues with it, and it's such an easy fix.

Comment: That question is from 2009, and is about a dead browser. There's very little value in perpetuating hacky fixes for dead browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can use it as follows:

```
 var that = $(this);
 $(img).load(function(){
      that.click(function(){ alert( 'loaded' }); 
 });
```

Once the `image` is loaded, the `click` event will be bound to the image.